# matrices raised to a fixed power

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is it true that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \ n\ge 2$, and a fixed $k \ge 2$, we can find matrices $X \in \mathcal{M}_{n}$ such that $X^k=\mathcal{M}_{n}$?

Comment: What do you mean, $X^k=M_n$?

Comment: I think the OP meant $\forall M\in\mathcal{M}_n$ it is possible to find matrices $X$ such that $X^k=M$

Comment: The question is basically if all the matrices from $\mathcal{M}_{n} $ can be written as a power $\ge 2$ of matrices from $\mathcal{M}_n $.

Comment: Here $\mathcal{M}_n$ is the set of all $n\times n$ matrices?

Comment: yes, it is the set of all the $n x n$ matrices.

Comment: The $\mathcal M_n$ the set of *real* $n \times n$ matrices? If so, we can already see that the statement cannot hold for $k = 2$, as $\det(X^2) = (\det X)^2 \geq 0$, but there are matrices $A$ such that $\det A < 0$, and so for these $X^2 \neq A$ for all $X$.

Comment: The matrices are complex.

Comment: Please edit the question, then, so it says what you mean to say, instead of saying something that makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Prove that there does not exists a matrix
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
such that
$$
A^2=\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
For $k>2$:

1) Show that $X^k=M^{-1}J^kM$ where $J$ is the Jordan canonical form of $X$.

2) prove (by induction) that for an upper triangular matrix 
$$
J=\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
0&c
\end{bmatrix}
$$
we have:
$$
J^k=\begin{bmatrix}
a^k&\frac{b}{a-c}(a^k-c^k)\\
0&c^k
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad \mbox{if} \quad a\ne c
$$
$$
J^k=\begin{bmatrix}
a^k&bka^{k-1}\\
0&a^k
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad \mbox{if} \quad a = c
$$

3) Prove that we cannot have
$$
J^k=\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: This holds for $k=2$. What about an odd $k$?

Comment: I've added to my answer. I hope it's useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Not ture. If it is ture, then $X^{k}=I_{n}$ for some $k$, where $I_{n}$ is $n\times n$ identity matrix. It implies that $X^{k+1}=X$. The set $\{X^{k}:k\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 2}\}$ forms a group. But $\mathcal{M}_{n}$ is not a group.